# How can I have a system boot in to a root session and then run a command within that session?

Tags: linux, root, startup

I have a GNU/Linux system with one account, the root account. When I boot the system, I want it to automatically log in to the root account and then run a 'telnet' command within that session. How can I do this?

My system does not have a GUI and I do not wish to install one unless necessary...

Comment: Does your system have a GUI?

Comment: Please don't answer comments in answers, [edit] your original post instead. You seem to have created a second account, if you've lost the credentials you used for the first one, please [merge](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.

Comment: Do you really need the root user to log in? If not, you could simply write yourself init.d script and run telnet in it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the kosher way to do it, but it does work:

The program that runs on a virtual terminal at startup is decided by the `/etc/inittab` file. These are all run as root. It has lines like these:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

They decide what ends up on which virtual terminal. `/sbin/getty` provides a virtual terminal. In my case, `/sbin/getty 38400 tty1` means `getty` provides `tty1` on the first virtual terminal. `getty` will then call `login`, and that's where the login prompts on the virtual terminals come from.

So there are two ways you could do this:

1. the quick-and-dirty way: just replace `/sbin/getty`, plus arguments, by telnet, for at least one of the virtual terminals, like so:

   ```
   1:2345:respawn:/usr/bin/telnet foo.bar
   ```

   This will probably work, but is not a very nice way to do it, as no tty is created. This might cause other problems if you want to use the machine for other things as well, so I recommend:
2. the proper way: install a `getty` replacement that can run any program, like `rungetty`. Then call *that*:

   ```
   1:2345:respawn:/sbin/rungetty tty1 -- /usr/bin/telnet foo.bar
   ```

Note: if you use `rungetty`, the program will run under the `nobody` user by default. This is almost always preferable to running programs as `root`, because it offers better security. If you *do* really need the `root` user (or any other user), use the `-u` switch.